# Database Error, Vendor Code 17

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2005, web-services, crystal-reports

I have a problem with creating an report in my Web-service with ASP. Locally everything works fine, connecting to Sql-Server or MySQL Server is no problem at all.

But now I am trying to connect to a Sql-Server 2005 and I get an error, something about a database vendor code 17 (it's a German version, so i won't directly post the whole error message).

I use the CR Version 12.0.0.683 and Visual Studio 2005.

Here is a little Code Snippet, to show you the way how the connection parameters are submitted

`ReportDocument repDoc = new ReportDocument();
repDoc.Load(fileName);
repDoc.DataSourceConnections[x].SetConnection(server, database, user, password);
 // now there are some params set and the report will be created.`

Does anybody know this bug and how i can get rid of him?

Comment: Show some more error message, i think that would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Error 17 in SQL Server is:

"Error: SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (Error code 17)."

So I'd start by checking the usual stuff: is the SQL Server running? Can you connect to it *outside* of your CR report?

See also: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3792 for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @p.marino said, this error code of Sqlserver and the error comes when database name or credentials not match or exist. The same error I get after my pc name change.

Idially we store this credentials for crystal report in web.config, my entries are:

```
<add key="ReportPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Timesheet\Reports\"/>
<add key="SaveAsPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Timesheet\Server\"/>
<add key="ServerName" value="MypcnameAsServerName\SQLSERVER2008R2"/>  <-- this entry cause the issue
<add key="DatabaseName" value="DBname"/>          
<add key="DBUser" value="sa"/>
<add key="DBPassword" value="sa@1234"/>
```

I think the answer will helpfulll to anybody.